# Cant edit start date in a new MOSS task

Tags: 2007, task-list

This has me stumped

I've gone to add a task to a task list on my Team Site. All of the fields are editable except Start Date, which is displayed as a label rather than a Date Picker.

I'm using the OOB Task content type in my task list, and I've not changed anything in the list itself. I've checked the column within the "ctypewss.xml" file in the hive and that has nothing to say this is read only. I've also tried making the column editable in a feature receiver by setting its ReadOnly flag to false.

None of this has made any difference, I still can't change the start date. Surely this doesn't default behavior - or perhaps it is?

Can anyone suggest what's happening?

Thanks

Comment: Is this happening in just this one task list or all task lists? What happens if you create a new one?

Comment: This seems to be happening in all task lists. I've also just noticed I'm getting the same thing when adding a Calendar item, which suggests it must be a problem with the Start Date column within the site. What's strange about this is it's just a normal OOB team site collection, with little customisation (and none that should affect site columns)